# How to automatically press 'Enter' key on change in value in textarea (using Pure JS)?

Tags: javascript

For the automated robot framework tests, I need to trigger the `Enter` keypress automatically on updating the value in the `textarea` using pure JavaScript. (in Console)

Tried the following, but didn't worked

```
function simulateEnterPress(element) {
    e = $.Event("keypress"); // Create a keypress event
    e.which = 13; // Set the pressed key to "Enter"
    element.trigger(e); // Trigger the event
}
function doAction() {
    inputElement = document.getElementById("vJSONValue").value; // Get the input element
    inputElement.value = ('[{"label":"oook"}]'); // Set value of the input
    simulateEnterPress(inputElement);
}
```

**Updated:**

> Need to update the `JSONeditor` through `textarea` [image]

Comment: Are you using a form with a submit button? if so you can just `button.click()`

Comment: No, actually, I'm trying to update a JSONeditor (ace-editor) using textarea.

Comment: [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) - MDN Docs